# C# Solr query - how to only get future dates?

Tags: c#, date, solr, filter

I have a search method that queries Solr for event items. I need to modify it to only get events where the date has not already passed (i.e. Where(x => x.EventDate.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date), but I'm not sure how to add this because I'm not very familiar with Solr. Here's my search function:

```
public SearchQueryResults Search(string keywords, int page,int perPage, List<Guid> contentTypeFilters, List<Guid> otherFilters, ISortBuilder<SearchResultItem> sortBuilder)
{
  var searchFilters = new List<IPredicateBuilder<SearchResultItem>>()
                    {
                      new IsSearchablePredicateBuilder()
                    };

  if (contentTypeFilters.Any())
  {
    var contentTypePredicateBuilder = new ContentTypePredicateBuilder();

    contentTypePredicateBuilder.ContentTypes = contentTypeFilters;

    searchFilters.Add(contentTypePredicateBuilder);
  }

  if (otherFilters.Any())
  {
    var tagFilterBuilder = new TagsAndPredicateBuilder(otherFilters,_sitecoreContext);

    searchFilters.Add(tagFilterBuilder);
  }

  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keywords))
  {
    keywords = "";
  }

  SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
  var queryParams = new Dictionary<string, string>() { };
  queryParams.Add("q", keywords);


  searchRequest.QueryParameters = queryParams;
  searchRequest.SortBy = "";
  searchRequest.SortOrder = "";

  SearchQuery<SearchResultItem> queryArguments = new SearchQuery<SearchResultItem>();
  queryArguments.FilterBuilders = searchFilters;

  queryArguments.Page = page;
  queryArguments.PerPage = perPage;
  queryArguments.FacetsBuilder = new SearchFacetBuilder<SearchResultItem>();
  queryArguments.SearchRequest = searchRequest;
  queryArguments.IndexName = _indexName;
  if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(keywords))
  {
    queryArguments.QueryBuilders =new List<IPredicateBuilder<SearchResultItem>>();
  }
  else
  {
    queryArguments.QueryBuilders = new[] { new KeywordPredicateBuilder<SearchResultItem>(new[] { keywords }) };
  }

  queryArguments.SortBuilder = sortBuilder;

  try
  {
    var results = _searchManager.GetResults<SearchResultItem>(queryArguments);


    SearchQueryResults queryResults = new SearchQueryResults();
    queryResults.ResultItems = results.Results;
    queryResults.CurrentPage = page;

    queryResults.TotalResults = Int32.Parse(results.TotalResults.ToString());

    queryResults.TotalPages = (queryResults.TotalResults + perPage - 1) / perPage; ;


    return queryResults;
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Error with FilteredSearch, could be a loss of connection to the SOLR server: " + exc.Message, this);
    return null;
  }
}
```

and here is how it's being called:

```
Results = _searchService.Search(searchTerm, CurrentPage - 1, 10, contentTypes, searchFilters,
    new GenericSortBuilder<SearchResultItem>(q => q.OrderByDescending(r => r.SearchDate)));
```

How do I add in date filtering so that it only returns items where the date is in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I would add filter query to the list of existing ones filtering the date field. On the documentation page, I was able to find information about [fluent API](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Fluent-API.md), which could help here

```
Query.Field("date").From(DateTime.Now)
```

I'm not C# developer, that this code could have some mistakes, but I think the main idea is clear what needs to be done.